# Конфликты js-скриптов

Tags: javascript, html

Могут ли быть конфликты если подключена библиотека jquery в основном сайте, а также подключена эта же либа jquery на сайте, который подгружается в iframe на первый сайт? Или в iframe это изолированные библиотеки, которые живут своей жизнью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iframe` изолирован, соответственно конфликтов быть не должно.